# Animate conditionnal *ngIf div height using css

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a `container` angular bloc that displays using *ngIf condition.

```
<div class="simulation-bloc">
  <ng-container *ngIf="type==='simulation'">
    bloc content
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

How can I  animate the height of this bloc when it shows ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this animation i have made from the angular built in library:

```js
//slideDown-animation.ts
import { animate, style, group, state, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

export const slideDownAnimation = trigger('slideDownAnimation', [
    state('in', style({
        'max-height': '1000px', 'opacity':1, 'overflow': 'visible'
    })),
    state('out', style({
        'max-height': '0px', 'opacity':1, 'overflow': 'hidden'
    })),
    transition('in => out', [group([
        animate('300ms ease-in-out', style({
            'opacity': '0'
        })),
        animate('300ms ease-in-out', style({
            'max-height': '0px'
        })),
        animate('300ms ease-in-out', style({
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        }))
    ]
    )]),
    transition('out => in', [group([
        animate('300ms ease-in-out', style({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        })),
        animate('300ms ease-in-out', style({
            'max-height': '500px'
        })),
        animate('300ms ease-in-out', style({
            'opacity': '1'
        }))
    ]
    )])
]);
```

```js
//in component.ts
import { slideDownAnimation } from "src/app/shared/animations/slideDown-animation";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout',
  templateUrl: './checkout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkout.component.css'],
  animations: [modalAnimations,slideDownAnimation]
})
export class...
```

```html
<!-- component.html -->
<div [@slideDownAnimation]="YourBooleanVariable?'in':'out'"></div>
```

A working sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ppyssn?file=src/app/slide.animation.ts

Comment: I have tried it , It works only when condition is true ( div became bigger ) but not when div goes off. Also Inside my div I have another `ngIf` condition that increase the height of the div , in this case also the animation is not working

Comment: I added the stackblitz link with a working sample